# Proof that Cov(W+Y, Y-V) = 0 given that W, Y, and V are uncorrelated but not independent

Tags: probability, expected-value, covariance

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$
I'm trying to prove the following statement: $\Cov(W+Y , Y-V) = 0$, given the following constraints:

1. $W$,$Y$, and $V$ are **Uncorrelated** but **not independent**
2. $E(W)=E(Y)=E(V)=\mu$
3. $V(W)=V(Y)=V(V)=\sigma^2.$

Can someone help me out with the sketch/proof ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$
The claim is false, if we make the assumption that $\sigma^2\not=0.$ "Uncorrelated" occurs if and only if the covariances are zero. We know that
\begin{align*}
\Cov(W+Y,Y-V)
&=\Cov(W,Y)-\Cov(W,V)+V(Y)-\Cov(Y,V)\\
&=0-0+\sigma^2-0\\
&=\sigma^2\\
&\not=0.
\end{align*}
The independence of the variables is irrelevant, as are the expected values.

Comment: is it gonna be 0 if W,X, and Y are independent?

Comment: No, because the same calculation is valid whether the variables are independent or not.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
Cov(W+Y,Y-V)&=Cov(W,Y)-Cov(W,V)+Cov(Y,Y)-Cov(Y,V)\\  
            &=0-0+\sigma^2-0\\
            &=\sigma^2
\end{align}
given that $$Cov(aW+bY,cY+dV)=ac Cov(W,Y)+ad Cov(W,V)+bc Cov(Y,Y)+bd Cov(Y,V)$$ $a=1,b=1,c=1,d=-1$ in this case, and $$Cov(Y,Y)=Var(Y)$$.